# Java interfaces - prevent code repetition

Tags: java, interface, wildcard, repeat, extends

I'm trying to create an interface for a set of classes,
but I am failing in finding a solution, which
prevents copying almost similar code for each new method in the
interface.

The interface

```
public interface P6BO<T extends BusinessObject> {
    String[] getFields();

    void create(T businessObject) throws P6BOException;
    void delete(T businessObject) throws P6BOException;
}
```

30+ implementations of the interface.

```
public class ActivityBO implements P6BO<Activity> {
    ...

    @Override
    public void create(Activity activity) throws P6BOException {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Activity activity) throws P6BOException {
        ...
    }
}
```

Container class to initialize all the implementations and 
provide a single point of access to each of them.

```
public class P6Bom {
    public final ActivityBO activity = new ActivityBO();
    public final EpsBO eps = new EpsBO();
    public final ResourceBO resource = new ResourceBO();

    public P6Bom(P6Info p6Info) throws P6BOException {
        activity.activate(p6Info, p6Cache, p6Buffer);
        eps.activate(p6Info, p6Cache, p6Buffer);
        resource.activate(p6Info, p6Cache, p6Buffer);
    }

    ...

    public void create(BusinessObject businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        if (businessObject instanceof Activity) {
            activity.create((Activity) businessObject);
        } else if (businessObject instanceof EPS) {
            eps.create((EPS) businessObject);
        } else if (businessObject instanceof Resource) {
            resource.create((Resource) businessObject);
        }
    }

    public void delete(BusinessObject businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        if (businessObject instanceof Activity) {
            activity.delete((Activity) businessObject);
        } else if (businessObject instanceof EPS) {
            eps.delete((EPS) businessObject);
        } else if (businessObject instanceof Resource) {
            resource.delete((Resource) businessObject);
        }
    }

    public P6BO<? extends BusinessObject> getBO(BusinessObject businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        if (businessObject instanceof Activity) {
            return activity;
        } else if (businessObject instanceof EPS) {
            return eps;
        } else if (businessObject instanceof Resource) {
            return resource;
        } else {
            throw new P6BOException("not implemented.");
        }
    }
}
```

The test class

```
public class Test() {
    /* Works: but is not generic (I cannot call the delete method for any BusinessObject). */
    Activity activity = new Activity("MyNewActivity");
    P6Bom.activity.create(activity);
    P6Bom.activity.delete(activity);

    /* Works: but results in a double administration in the P6Bom */
    Activity activity = new Activity("MyNewActivity");
    P6Bom.create(activity);
    P6Bom.delete(activity);

    /* Compiler error
       The method delete(capture#1-of ? extends BusinessObject)
       in the type P6BO<capture#1-of ? extends BusinessObject>
       is not applicable for the arguments (Activity)
    */

    p6Bom.getBO(activity).delete(activity);
}
```

What would be an elegant solution to prevent the repetitive administration of each method in the P6Bom interface?

Comment: If the implementation is exact for almost every Activity class I would create a default method in the interface with this implementation. If you need to change the default implementation, just override the method.

Comment: @Embid123 I think OPs problem is the code in P6BoM, not a repition of the implementations in the 30+ implementations.

Comment: have you considered `abstract` classes ? Then your implementations could extend the abstract class, profit from some generic implemented methods and implement the interface

Comment: Use reflection to determine the type and invoke the appropriate thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a map:

```
public class P6Bom {
    public final Map<Class<? extends P6BO<? extends BusinessObject>>, P6BO<? extends BusinessObject>>> classMap;

    public P6Bom(P6Info p6Info) throws P6BOException {
        classMap = new HashMap<>();
        classMap.put(ActivityBo.class, new ActivityBO());
        ...
        for(var bo: classMap.values()) {
         bo.activate(p6Info, p6Cache, p6Buffer);
        }
    }

    ...

    public void create(BusinessObject businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        getBO(businessObject).create(businessObject);
    }

    public P6BO<? extends BusinessObject> getBO(BusinessObject businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        if (classMap.containsKey(businessObject.getClass())) {
            return classMap.get(businessObject.getClass());
        } else {
            throw new P6BOException("not implemented.");
        }
    }
}
```

I forget if the `<? extends BusinessObject>` allows you to do that. If the compiler complains, omit that part in the classMap declaration and the getBO signature and ignore the warnings ;-)

The thing to remember here is that in the bytecode, the generics are removed, so the actual method signature allows you always to pass in BusinessObjects. Once inside the method, it will be cast and throw a RuntimeException if the class doesn't match, but from the compiler/interface side, it is perfectly possible to write code like that.

Comment: Since the creation mechanism in the constructor will need you to enumerate all the types, I would move it in the methods below. If it's the first-ever invocation with this type - add it to the map, activate it and then proceed :)

Comment: @RoyalBg You will need to enumerate them somewhere, whether that's in the constructor or somewhere else. The key point is to only have to do it once.

Comment: The create method generates the same error (not a warning):

The method create(capture#6-of ? extends BusinessObject) in the type P6BO<capture#6-of ? extends BusinessObject> is not applicable for the arguments (BusinessObject)

Comment: @ArthurBorsboom Yes, remove the `<? extends BusinessObject>` from the return value declaration of `getBO`.

Comment: It seems that removing the type parameter from the getBO method, making the return value a raw type, and adding two SuppressWarnings, seem to work. It is also nice that these supressions stay in the 'API' (transparent to the user) and the user does not clug its code with SupressWarnings. I am satisfied with this solution, however I am going to wait for other answers before accepting this answer as the best answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a classical `factory` and `strategy` pattern issue, where the `Open/Closed` principle is violated. You want to extend your application, but without modifying it.

@kutschkem's solution is so far the most elegant way. In addition I would suggest to instantiate the strategy/business object manager when the first business object is created.

This will free your hands from enumerating the `BOM`'s, because the suggested way, the `Open/Closed` principle is still violated. Once a new business object is introduced, its respective manager needs to be added in the class.

The solution could be the following:

```
public class P6Bom {
    private final Map<String, P6BO<? extends BusinessObject>> classMap;

    private final P6Info info;

    private final P6Cache cache;

    private final P6Buffer buffer;

    public P6Bom(P6Info info, P6Cache cache, P6Buffer buffer) {
        this.classMap = new HashMap<>();
        this.info = info;
        this.cache = cache;
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public <T extends BusinessObject> void create(T businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        this.getBO(businessObject).create(businessObject);
    }

    public <T extends BusinessObject> P6BO<T> getBO(T businessObject) throws P6BOException {
        if (!this.classMap.containsKey(businessObject.getClass().getName())) {
            try {
                var bo = (P6BO<T>)Class.forName(businessObject.getClass().getPackageName() + ".bo." + businessObject.getClass().getSimpleName() + "BO").getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
                bo.activate(this.info, this.cache, this.buffer)
                this.classMap.put(
                        businessObject.getClass().getName(),
                        bo
                );
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new P6BOException("not implemented.");
            }
        }

        return (P6BO<T>)this.classMap.get(businessObject.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Of course, for that solution there need to be a convention (or configuration) how strategies (e.g. ActivityBO) could be found for `BusinessObjects`. In the example, they live in a subpackage called `bo`.

Comment: That is nice addition! I am going to have a look if this cleans up the P6Bom (P6 BusinessObjectManager) even more and makes the code more readable. Currently not everything fits in the interface / contract; I first have to deal with the exceptions...